# how to open any network file on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Currently, I am using `open_file: ^3.0.1` plugin for an open local disk file. But How to open any network file? I store the file on Firebase Storage and I read URL.

for Local File open

```
OpenFile.open(path);
```

I stored any type of file to firebase storage... And also I load all files from firebase storage. Users can open(view) these particular files

> Example:
>
> Url 1 = https://... - image
>
> Url 2 = https:// - pdf
>
> Url 3 = https:// -
> word

Comment: What you mean "any network file"?  If you're talking just about files uploaded to Cloud Storage, then you should use the SDK provided by Firebase.

Comment: I stored any type of file to firebase storage... And also I load all files from firebase storage. Users can open(view) these particular files.

Comment: @DougStevenson Do you understand what I need? sorry for bad English

Comment: You can download the file in `getTemporaryDirectory()` (package: [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)). Then you can use  `OpenFile.open(path)` to open it.

Comment: `getTemporaryDirectory()` returns a cache directory for respective platform. I believe its suitable for your scenario.

Comment: thanks @CrazyLazyCat can I use this plugin for download? `flutter_downloader: ^1.4.1`

Comment: Sorry I haven't used this plugin [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader). you can try.

Answer (score 0):

One way of accessing files from a network is downloading the file to a temporary directory on your device. You can use [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) to achieve this. Once downloaded, you can read the file from the path.

But since you're using Firebase Cloud Storage, follow this [guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#downloading-files) to download the file. If you wish to only temporarily store the file, you can delete the file when not in use anymore.